# memcpy used in DLL and loaded in another application, but the memory is changing itself, did i do something wrong?

Tags: c++, memory, dll, memcpy

**This problem is fixed, thanks for pointing out the mistake in declaration of the typedef.
in which i am missing _stdcall to it. After digging some materials it is something about calling conventions, somehow it treat the stack in different way. I am not really sure, but it seems fixed it. Thanks**

Greetings and Hello everyone, 
I am currently working on an DLL which provide Serial Port Communication and then write to the buffer the result.
Lets say the DLL function part is DLL,
and Application part be EXE.

After certain process, I will be able to create a string in DLL function.
And then i used memcpy to copy the buffer in DLL to the char* pointer the EXE provide

However, it is fine sometime with all bytes copied ,
and the EXE can dump the result just the same as the DLL has written, 
but sometimes it has shown the correct values in DLL function part,
but in EXE the memory section has become gibberish.

I want to know if i am missing some obvious part, as i am not really experienced in memory and how Extern Modules works with it.

I will now post DLL part and EXE part code for your reference.

**DLL Part:** compiled in VC++ 2012
**dumpstr : dump the first 20 bytes from the address given.**
**mp_get_var is exported via a .def file and exported to a DLL**

```
void dumpstr(char* charC, char* desc) {
     printf("\n= S T A R T ===\nDLL Dumping the %s Array...\n", desc);
     int i;
    for(i=0; i<20; i++) {
             printf("%p:%3d | ", charC+i, *(charC+i));
             if((i+1)%4==0) printf("\n");
             }
    printf("\n==E N D====\n");
     }
int _stdcall mp_get_var(char* inSI, char* cParam, int paramIndex, char *outSI) {
    //std::string returnValue = MyConvert::get_fieldvalue2(inSI,cParam, paramIndex);
    printf("ON DLL START, INSI ADDR (%p)\n", inSI);
    printf("ON DLL START, OUTSI ADDR (%p)\n", outSI);
    dumpstr(outSI, "PREV OUTSI");
    //printf("DLL received: %s\n", inSI);
    //dumpstr(inSI, "THIS > INSI");
    std::string returnValue = "EPTATROPICAL";
    memcpy(outSI,returnValue.c_str(),returnValue.length());  

    //*(outSI + returnValue.length()) = '\0';
    //printf("DLL copied outSI: %s\n", outSI);
    dumpstr(outSI, "THIS COPIED OUTSI");
    printf("ON DLL END, INSI ADDR (%p)\n", inSI);
    printf("ON DLL END, OUTSI ADDR (%p)\n", outSI);
    return returnValue.length();
}
```

**EXE Part:** compiled in Dev-C++
I import the library using the following statements:
and i do two request to the DLL function which respectively using **Result2** and **Result3** as output buffer.

```
typedef int (*mp_get_var)(char * , char* , int , char *);
int main() {
    HINSTANCE hLib = LoadLibrary("MPComsDLL.dll");
    MP_GET_VAR = (mp_get_var)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hLib, "mp_get_var");

    sprintf(cRequest, "EPAMTOH");
//using **Result2** char array for result buffer.
    returnval = MP_GET_VAR(Result, cRequest, 1, Result2);
    printf("ON EXE, OUTSI address : %p", Result2);
    printf("%s return length: %d\n", cRequest, returnval);
    dumpstr(Result2);

    sprintf(cRequest, "MERCHANTID");
//using **Result3** char array for result buffer.
    returnval = MP_GET_VAR(Result, cRequest, 1, Result3);
    printf("ON EXE, OUTSI address : %p", Result3);
    printf("%s return length: %d\n", cRequest, returnval);
    dumpstr(Result3);
}
```

However, here is the screen dump:
**For the first call**

```
ON DLL START, INSI ADDR (0028F8B0)
ON DLL START, OUTSI ADDR (0028F680)

= S T A R T ===
DLL Dumping the PREV OUTSI Array...
0028F680:  0 | 0028F681:  0 | 0028F682:  0 | 0028F683:  0 |
0028F684:  0 | 0028F685:  0 | 0028F686:  0 | 0028F687:  0 |
0028F688:  0 | 0028F689:  0 | 0028F68A:  0 | 0028F68B:  0 |
0028F68C:  0 | 0028F68D:  0 | 0028F68E:  0 | 0028F68F:  0 |
0028F690:  0 | 0028F691:  0 | 0028F692:  0 | 0028F693:  0 |

==E N D====

= S T A R T ===
DLL Dumping the THIS COPIED OUTSI Array...
0028F680: 69 | 0028F681: 80 | 0028F682: 84 | 0028F683: 65 |
0028F684: 84 | 0028F685: 82 | 0028F686: 79 | 0028F687: 80 |
0028F688: 73 | 0028F689: 67 | 0028F68A: 65 | 0028F68B: 76 |
0028F68C:  0 | 0028F68D:  0 | 0028F68E:  0 | 0028F68F:  0 |
0028F690:  0 | 0028F691:  0 | 0028F692:  0 | 0028F693:  0 |

==E N D====
ON DLL END, INSI ADDR (0028F8B0)
ON DLL END, OUTSI ADDR (0028F680)
ON EXE, OUTSI address : 0028F680佩 return length: 12
```

**DLL side ended for first call
Here is the dumping in EXE part for the same address.**

```
----
Now Dumping the Char Array...
0028F680: 69 | 0028F681: 80 | 0028F682: 84 | 0028F683: 65 |
0028F684: 84 | 0028F685: 82 | 0028F686: 79 | 0028F687: 80 |
0028F688: 73 | 0028F689: 67 | 0028F68A: 65 | 0028F68B: 76 |
0028F68C:  0 | 0028F68D:  0 | 0028F68E:  0 | 0028F68F:  0 |
0028F690:  0 | 0028F691:  0 | 0028F692:  0 | 0028F693:  0 |
```

**Dumping finish in EXE part, you can see it is the same as DLL part dump, so I assume it is working normally.**

*Then here it comes the next call, which use **Result3** as buffer. I see it has address from **0028F450***

```
ON DLL START, INSI ADDR (0028F8B0)
ON DLL START, OUTSI ADDR (0028F450)

= S T A R T ===
DLL Dumping the PREV OUTSI Array...
0028F450:  0 | 0028F451:  0 | 0028F452:  0 | 0028F453:  0 |
0028F454:  0 | 0028F455:  0 | 0028F456:  0 | 0028F457:  0 |
0028F458:  0 | 0028F459:  0 | 0028F45A:  0 | 0028F45B:  0 |
0028F45C:  0 | 0028F45D:  0 | 0028F45E:  0 | 0028F45F:  0 |
0028F460:  0 | 0028F461:  0 | 0028F462:  0 | 0028F463:  0 |

==E N D====

= S T A R T ===
DLL Dumping the THIS COPIED OUTSI Array...
0028F450: 69 | 0028F451: 80 | 0028F452: 84 | 0028F453: 65 |
0028F454: 84 | 0028F455: 82 | 0028F456: 79 | 0028F457: 80 |
0028F458: 73 | 0028F459: 67 | 0028F45A: 65 | 0028F45B: 76 |
0028F45C:  0 | 0028F45D:  0 | 0028F45E:  0 | 0028F45F:  0 |
0028F460:  0 | 0028F461:  0 | 0028F462:  0 | 0028F463:  0 |

==E N D====
ON DLL END, INSI ADDR (0028F8B0)
ON DLL END, OUTSI ADDR (0028F450)
ON EXE, OUTSI address : 0028F450MERCHANTID return length: 12
```

Strange started from here, I see in **0028F450** in DLL, it should be

```
69,80,84,65,84,82,79,80,73,67,65,76
```

However... The dump in exe become like this,
But it becomes

```
0,0,68,0,83,-12,40,0,0,0,0,0
```

The dump is here  still at address **0028F450**

```
----
Now Dumping the Char Array...
0028F450:  0 | 0028F451:  0 | 0028F452: 68 | 0028F453:  0 |
0028F454: 83 | 0028F455:-12 | 0028F456: 40 | 0028F457:  0 |
0028F458:  0 | 0028F459:  0 | 0028F45A:  0 | 0028F45B:  0 |
0028F45C:  0 | 0028F45D:  0 | 0028F45E:  0 | 0028F45F:  0 |
0028F460:  0 | 0028F461:  0 | 0028F462:  0 | 0028F463:  0 |
```

Just for your reference, here is the **third call**, with **Result2** again as the buffer:
However, this hasnt been changed to gibberish mysteriously.

```
ON DLL START, INSI ADDR (0028F8B0)
ON DLL START, OUTSI ADDR (0028F680)

= S T A R T ===
DLL Dumping the PREV OUTSI Array...
0028F680: 69 | 0028F681: 80 | 0028F682: 84 | 0028F683: 65 |
0028F684: 84 | 0028F685: 82 | 0028F686: 79 | 0028F687: 80 |
0028F688: 73 | 0028F689: 67 | 0028F68A: 65 | 0028F68B: 76 |
0028F68C:  0 | 0028F68D:  0 | 0028F68E:  0 | 0028F68F:  0 |
0028F690:  0 | 0028F691:  0 | 0028F692:  0 | 0028F693:  0 |

==E N D====

= S T A R T ===
DLL Dumping the THIS COPIED OUTSI Array...
0028F680: 69 | 0028F681: 80 | 0028F682: 84 | 0028F683: 65 |
0028F684: 84 | 0028F685: 82 | 0028F686: 79 | 0028F687: 80 |
0028F688: 73 | 0028F689: 67 | 0028F68A: 65 | 0028F68B: 76 |
0028F68C:  0 | 0028F68D:  0 | 0028F68E:  0 | 0028F68F:  0 |
0028F690:  0 | 0028F691:  0 | 0028F692:  0 | 0028F693:  0 |

==E N D====
ON DLL END, INSI ADDR (0028F8B0)
ON DLL END, OUTSI ADDR (0028F680)
TERMINALID return length: 12

----
Now Dumping the Char Array...
0028F680: 69 | 0028F681: 80 | 0028F682: 84 | 0028F683: 65 |
0028F684: 84 | 0028F685: 82 | 0028F686: 79 | 0028F687: 80 |
0028F688: 73 | 0028F689: 67 | 0028F68A: 65 | 0028F68B: 76 |
0028F68C:  0 | 0028F68D:  0 | 0028F68E:  0 | 0028F68F:  0 |
0028F690:  0 | 0028F691:  0 | 0028F692:  0 | 0028F693:  0 |
```

I am confusing now and wasted a whole day on it, any further guidance is much appreciated :)
If i needed to supply more information, i would be glad to do so, thanks for your help.

Comment: I haven't verified this, but you may want to ensure the calling convention of your pointer-to-function is properly coded. I.e. , your typedef appears to be missing `_stdcall`. Worth a shot, anyway.

Comment: Thank you, WhozCraig, seems it fixed the problem somehow.